# How to write a formula for generating row of sequential numbers at a fixed amount?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I am trying to set up an **excel** file that will be used for filter outcome of our trials in plant. I want to have a **macro** or **formula** that uses a calculated value (e.g 3457 or 6558 or 12557) to have a sequential numbers inputed into rows. 
Just one column starting from 1,2,3,4.. up to 3457. I know there is an autofill option but if possible I want to manage this automatically without letting end users do it.

Answer (score 0):

Formula put this in the first cell of the list and copy it down to the end of the row:

```
=IF(ROW(1:1)<=$B$1,ROW(1:1),"")
```

Where B1 is the location of the max number.

Comment: I have done as you told me but first cell (A1) is one but the others (A2, A3,.... ) are all blank

Comment: I change the formula try the newest.  It should have been `<=` not `>`

Comment: replace B1 with $B$1 and try again

Comment: @Jo.lass yup missed that.  Good catch.

Comment: replacing worked. one question thought, is it possible to make this automatic without needing to copy formula manually to all the cells below ?

Comment: Not without vba. @BORGANOR

Comment: I am not familiar with coding in vba